# How to send nested image using axios in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, form-data

How to post this type of image value using axios in reactjs:

```
{
 "key1":value1,
 "key2":value2,
 "key3":{ "image":imagevalue,
          "key":value}
 }
```

Comment: For example, you could convert the image to base64, so `imageValue` would be a base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

I've only done this using fetch, but I think the principle is mostly the same. When you want to send a POST request that includes JSON keys and files (like images), you need to send it as a formData. For a single file with a couple of keys it would look like:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file[]", file);
formData.append("info", JSON.stringify({ key1: '...', key2: '...' }));
```

It is very likely that you will need to set your headers right before you proceed with your request:

```js
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=something');
```

After this you will be ready to send your request, which will look like:

```js
{
      method: "POST",
      headers
      body: formData,
      redirect: "follow",
    }
```